# Python: how to save a geotiff file using rasterio with coordinates?

Tags: python, rasterio

I masked a geotiff raster with a shapefile as described below

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.plot import show
import geopandas as gpd

population = rasterio.open('myData.tif')
gdf = gpd.read_file('myFile.shp')
clipped_array, clipped_transform = 
rasterio.mask.mask(population, [mapping(ps.iloc[0].geometry)], crop=True)

f,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
gdf.boundary.plot(ax=ax, lw=3, color='red')
show(clipped_array, transform=clipped_transform, ax=ax)
ax.set_xlim([1.82, 2.74])
ax.set_ylim([48.51, 49.14])
```

[image]

Now I would like to save the new data as a `.tif` file with coordinates and information.

Comment: Did you try my answer below? Let me know what else you need if it doesn't answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write to a new .tif using this. Since rasterio needs some meta for writing, it's common to use an input raster, such as in this case with adjusted attributes.

```
import rasterio
import os
import fiona
from rasterio import mask


with fiona.open('myFile.shp', "r") as shapefile:
    shapes = [feature["geometry"] for feature in shapefile]

with rasterio.open('myData.tif') as src:
    out_meta = src.meta
    out_image, out_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(src, shapes=shapes, crop=True)

    
    profile = src.profile
    profile["height"] = out_image.shape[1]
    profile["width"] = out_image.shape[2]
    profile["transform"] = out_transform

   
    out_meta.update({"driver": "GTiff",
                 "height": out_image.shape[1],
                 "width": out_image.shape[2],
                 "transform": out_transform})

with rasterio.open("masked.tif", "w", **out_meta) as dest:
    dest.write(out_image)
```